# Exactly one root of the quadratic expression is in given interval.

Tags: roots, quadratics

Question is,

Find the set of all values of 'a' so that the equation $f(x) = x^2 + (a-3)x + a =0$ has exactly one root $\alpha$ in the interval $(1,2)$ and $f(x+α) = 0$ has exactly one root in the interval $(0,1)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2963606/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Answer (score 0):

The second condition implies that there is exactly one root in $(\alpha,\alpha+1)$. As $\alpha$ is the only root in $(1,2)$, the second root must in fact be in $[2,\alpha+1)$.
The way the parabola looks, we must have $f(1)>0$, $f(2)\le 0$, and the difference between the roots must be between $0$ and $1$. Do you know how the the discriminant relates to that difference?